# Append an object to a JSON file with a correct format

Tags: php, json

In a Symfony project, I have a user-contacts.json file which contains :

```
[
    {
        "id": 137,
        "userName": "testUserName",
        "userEmail": "test@email.com",
        "userQuestion": "This is my question ?",
        "solved": false
    }
]
```

In a service, I'm receiving an object coming from a symfony form, here is the content:

```
 ContactFile.php on line 18:
    App\Entity\Contact {#561 ▼
      -id: 146
      -userName: "Contact"
      -userEmail: "test@test.com"
      -userQuestion: "test ?"
      -solved: false
    }
```

I'd like to append this contact query to the user-contacts.json file, in a way that the user-contacts.json content has a valid JSON format, like so for example:

```
[
    {
        "id": 137,
        "userName": "testUserName",
        "userEmail": "test@email.com",
        "userQuestion": "This is my question ?",
        "solved": false
    },
    {
        "id": 138,
        "userName": "anotherUserName",
        "userEmail": "another@email.com",
        "userQuestion": "This is another question ?",
        "solved": false
    }
]
```

Unfortunately, here is my result right now:

```
[
    [
        {
            "id": 148,
            "userName": "anotherUserName",
            "userEmail": "another@email.com",
            "userQuestion": "Another question?",
            "solved": false
        }
    ],
    {
        "id": 149,
        "userName": "test",
        "userEmail": "test@test.com",
        "userQuestion": "Question ?",
        "solved": false
    }
]
```

Here is my service code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use App\Entity\Contact;
use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;

class ContactFile
{
    public function __construct(private Filesystem $filesystem, private SerializerInterface $serializer) {}

    public function writeContactFile(Contact $contact): void
    {
        $actualFileContent = file_get_contents('../user-contacts/user-contacts.json');
        $requestContent = $this->serializer->serialize($contact, 'json');
        
        $array[] = json_decode($actualFileContent, true);
        $array[] = json_decode($requestContent, true);
       
        $result = json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    
        $this->filesystem->remove(['file', '../user-contacts/', 'user-contacts.json']);
        $this->filesystem->appendToFile('../user-contacts/user-contacts.json', $result);
    }
}
```

How would you append this "Contact" object to the user-contacts.json file, while having a standard JSON format?

Comment: `$array[] = json_decode($actualFileContent, true);` - here you are creating an additional array dimension. What you are decoding already _is_ an array.

Comment: You're right, but when I only do:
$array[] = $actualFileContent;

I get this type of data:
`[
    "{\"id\":157,\"userName\":\"sdf\",\"userEmail\":\"sdfsf@sdf.com\",\"userQuestion\":\"sdfsdf ?\",\"solved\":false}",
]`

Comment: Now you manipulated the wrong side of that assignment ... _This:_ `json_decode($actualFileContent, true);` results in an array. So assign the result to a variable, without wrapping it into an additional array - `$array = json_decode($actualFileContent, true);`

Comment: I think I understand what is going wrong: When I'm getting the current json file content, I'm getting something like this : 

`string(351) "[ "[\n {\n \"id\": 174,\n \"userName\": \"dfsdf\",\n \"userEmail\": \"sdfsfd@qf.com\",\n \"userQuestion\": \"sdf@sdf.com\",\n \"solved\": false\n }\n]", { "id": 175, "userName": "sdsd", "userEmail": "qsd@dsf.com", "userQuestion": "dfdsf", "solved": false } ]" `

No problem when adding a new content, but the old one is now full of backslashes.

If I want to remove backslashes, I can use json_decode, but it makes another array dimension..

Comment: It looks like your existing file has been messed up... you should make the change @CBroe suggested and start with a new, blank file

Answer (score 0):

As Cbroe said:
I replaced `$array[] = json_decode($actualFileContent, true);` to `$array = $actualFileContent;`

And now it's working. Thank you.